# rotate Frame in JavaCV

Tags: java, android, image, ffmpeg, javacv

I write simple app for android whick use FFmpeg + JavaCV. I can capture image from camera and can recorde video. But want to rotate frame when record video, don't can :-(

[Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h42rY.png)

Stop and save code:

```
public void stopRecording() {

        runAudioThread = false;
        try {
            audioThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioRecordRunnable = null;
        audioThread = null;


        if (recorder != null && recording) {
            if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Writing frames");
                try {
                    int firstIndex = imagesIndex % samples.length;
                    int lastIndex = (imagesIndex - 1) % images.length;
                    if (imagesIndex <= images.length) {
                        firstIndex = 0;
                        lastIndex = imagesIndex - 1;
                    }
                    if ((startTime = timestamps[lastIndex] - RECORD_LENGTH * 1000000L) < 0) {
                        startTime = 0;
                    }
                    if (lastIndex < firstIndex) {
                        lastIndex += images.length;
                    }
                    for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                        long t = timestamps[i % timestamps.length] - startTime;
                        if (t >= 0) {
                            if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                                recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                            }
                            recorder.record(images[i % images.length]);
                        }
                    }

                    firstIndex = samplesIndex % samples.length;
                    lastIndex = (samplesIndex - 1) % samples.length;
                    if (samplesIndex <= samples.length) {
                        firstIndex = 0;
                        lastIndex = samplesIndex - 1;
                    }
                    if (lastIndex < firstIndex) {
                        lastIndex += samples.length;
                    }
                    for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                        recorder.recordSamples(samples[i % samples.length]);
                    }
                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            recording = false;
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder = null;

        }
    }
```

in step `recorder.record(images[i % images.length]);` 
need rotate frame (images parameter)

How can help me ? Thank you.